# Css: Two containers above each other in an absolute positioned div cointainer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a div container with an absolute position. I want to place two canvas containers in it, but they should be above each other and not next to each other.

All three containers will have the same dimensions.

HTML:

```
<div height="100" width="100" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top: 10px;>
  <canvas height="100" width="100"></canvas>
  <canvas height="100" width="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Sorry for the question, I'm not very experienced with css.

Comment: then `canvas` will overflow out of the `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to position both the canvas on top if each other.. To achieve this You sould make both the canvas `position: avsolute ; top:0 ; left : 0`

then Your code will be like

```
<div height="100" width="100" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top: 10px;>
  <canvas height="100" width="100" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px" ></canvas>
  <canvas height="100" width="100" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px"  ></canvas>
</div>
```

what else you can do is give both the `canves` a class for example `.is-absolute`

then your code will be

```
<div height="100" width="100" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top: 10px;>
  <canvas height="100" width="100" class="is-absolute"></canvas>
  <canvas height="100" width="100" class="is-absolute"></canvas>
</div>
```

and css

```
<style>
 .is-absolute{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left :0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `canvas` is an inline element by default, add a `display:block` to the `canvas` elements for them to appear over each other. Also, the div's height should be 2x of the canvas height in order to contain both the canvas elements.

```css
canvas {
background: pink; /*only for the demo*/
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div height="200" width="100" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top: 10px;">
  <canvas height="100" width="100"></canvas>
  <canvas height="100" width="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: The canvas objects are now among themselves.